# Write Parceable with Timer class

Tags: java, android, timer

I'm new on Android app and I would work with Parceable, for send my class through **Intent**.

I have written a Class that has some properties, and among the others properties like id, description, I have a **Timer**.

MyClass is something like:

```
MyClass implements Parcelable{
  private int id;
  private String description
  private Timer chrono; 

  @Override
  public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(id);
    dest.writeString(description);
    //and for  write Timer?

  }
  public MyClass(Parcel in) {
    id = in.readInt();
    description = in.readString();
    //for read timer
  }
}
```

So How can I use parceable with **Timer** in my Class?

Comment: you can't. If you need, you could parcel whatever your timer is counting and instantiate it again

Comment: Thankyou for reply. But If I wantend make a Stop and Resume?